# Notification are currently provided by 'KDE plasma'

Tags: kubuntu, notification, notification-area

I have problem with my notifications, my notifications are currently provided by 'KDE plasma' and I can't fix it

Look at my setting:

[image]

Look at my notification bar:

[image]

I try that too:

[image]
In here i unable all of applications show notification in don't disturb mode but he's not work too

My version of Kubuntu is this:

[image]

I need your help for fix this problem :)

Comment: I know we have some questions about this problem but my version and settings is not use on these questions so i ask it again

Answer (score 1):

I'm late but I just solved this problem minutes ago. I removed from my desktop all widgets/plasmoids/interactive elements that could display notifications (I also disabled the notifications in the system tray just in case) except the notifications widget, which I wanted to use.

After that I rebooted to restart plasma and everything was OK.

It was [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/ibnnuj/does_anyone_know_how_to_enable_notifications_on/) post that helped me.

Comment: thanks so much but yes you are late now I'm gnome user